# NoMethodError in Controller#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

**undefined method `search' for #**

I am keeps on getting the above NoMethodError in controller index even the method is present in the model. Following is my model and controller. Where am I getting things wrong?

**Controller:**

```
    def index
      @ratings = Clerk::Rating.search(params).paginate(:per_page => 10, :page => params[:page])
    end
```

**Model:**

```
module Clerk
  class Rating < Base
    # Relationships
    belongs_to :application
    belongs_to :consumer

    def self.search(params)
       ratings = all
     if params[:search].present?
       ratings = ratings.joins(:consumer).where('phone like ? or lower(email) like ? or lower(first_name) like ? or lower(last_name) like ?',"%#{params[:search]}%","%#{params[:search].downcase}%","%#{params[:search].downcase}%","%#{params[:search].downcase}%")
     end
       ratings
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Error on what? It must be more specific than that.

Comment: @Iceman please see my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Have you included the module in your controller?

Add `include Clerk` just below the class definition and retry the action again.